# jQuery iframe onload

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I have an iframe that represents the content of my main page and it loads a different src depending on the menu option chosen. I want to perform a series of actions as soon as the iFrame is loaded but I cant seem to get it to work. The code looks more or less like the following:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#navigation').load(function () {
        alert('frame loaded!')
    });
});
```

Comment: What version of jquery are you using? `.load` for event binding was deprecated in jQuery 1.8

Comment: I see, I'm using 1.9.2, I will try it with on("load and see what happens.

Answer (score 2):

`.load` for event binding was deprecated in jQuery 1.8, use `.on("load"` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I asume this function is in your iFrame and will be executed after the document loading. If not - ther is some conceptual error. Anyway - the load function in jQuery will try to load a html document or piece of it in the object you specify - http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: What will be executed is where the alert function is now. I'm just including that as a "placeholder" to indicate that I will include some code there.

Comment: What I mean is - you use $(obj).load('...') to load your content in the frame. When you execute $(document).ready() in the iFrame you can't put "load" there, that's make no sense. What you have to do there is "perform a series of actions", just remove the "load" part and your code, the alert, will be executed.